# GOOGLE CLOUD STORAGE - how can i know if syncing successfully

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, rsync

Sorry if my English's bad.

I'm going to use Google Cloud Storage with rsync on my apps.
This apps creates files on a folder, then these can be synced to google storage using rsync (example: gsutil rsync /folder gs://destination)
But on my purpose, I need to know when the sync success and the link of file that synced successful. 
Is that have an API to do this. In my thought, after synced successful, google storage would return a JSON to the client to notify that the sync done. But i'm not sure it's right or not.

Can any one help me. Please

Answer (score 1):

gsutil rsync will complete with an exit code of 0 if the sync operation completed successfully. Behind the scenes, gsutil rsync is sending JSON API requests to Google Cloud Storage, and checking the result status of each operation as it completes. It also retries when operations fail in a way that can be retried.

Comment: I'm sorry but gsutil rsync is supposed to be a cron job that will not exit. It's syncing whenever the source folder had a change.So that, what does the "an exit code of 0" mean. or i'm misunderstanding how  gsutil rsync works. Can you please explain this thing in more detailed

Comment: You can run gsutil from cron, but I don't follow why you're saying the job would not exit. gsutil runs until it completes all work it needs to do and then exits. Maybe you mean your cron job is set to run in an infinite loop, running gsutil rsync and then sleeping and then repeating? If so, each gsutil run will finish with an exit code indicating if it succeeded.

Comment: Sorry for the last comment, I mean it'll run as a background apps, not as a cron job. I assumed that I start it once and after that, it will sync my file in folder whenever my files had a change.Am i misundertood